# How to systematically extract the arguments of exponentials

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a diagonal eigenvalue matrix with all diagonal entries being of the form: A*exp(b).

All I want to do is scan these entries and grab the argument of the exponentials, b, and put them in a vector.

Is this possible? I am new at *Mathematica* so anything helps!

Comment: How are the entries written?  Give at least one example.  For example, we can write 0.449144 as $A \exp (b)$ for an infinite number of pairs of $A$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Let

```
m = DiagonalMatrix[{A1 Exp[b1], A2 Exp[b2], A3 Exp[b3]}];
```

Then

```
Cases[m, Exp[x_] :> x, Infinity]
```

> {b1, b2, b3}

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear the format of your matrix.  If diagonal entries are numerical, you can extract them and form a vector by using `Diagonal`

```
myDiagonalMatrix = DiagonalMatrix[Table[RandomReal[] Exp[RandomReal[]], {5}]]
```

(*
{{1.31275, 0., 0., 0., 0.}, 
 {0., 0.230657, 0., 0., 0.}, 
 {0., 0., 0.675358, 0., 0.}, 
 {0., 0., 0., 0.0772588, 0.}, 
 {0., 0., 0., 0., 0.315459}}
*)

```
Diagonal[myDiagonalMatrix]
```

(*
{1.31275, 0.230657, 0.675358, 0.0772588, 0.315459}
*)

If you have a *symbolic* entries (and I wonder how you would ever generate them), then use @corey979's solution.